# Download, Install and Configure New Drupal Instance within drush script

Tags: drush

I am writing script to download, install and configure new Drupal site. The download and install steps are working, however. In the third step - configuration, i would like drush to bootstrap from the new installed directory, so the Drupal API is available for functions such as variable_set(),drupal_parse_info_file(). Here is the script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush
<?php

$default_dest = 'test-core';
$default_make = '../builds/build-drupal-core.make';
$make_file = ($build_src = drush_get_option('build-src', FALSE)) ? $build_src : $default_make;
$dest = ($build_dest = drush_get_option('build-dest', FALSE)) ? $build_dest : $default_dest;
$status = _process_make_file($make_file, $dest);
drush_print('Make Download '.(($status) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE" ));

# Site
##########################################################
$siteName="Test Site";
$siteSlogan="Some test site";
$siteLocale="en";
##########################################################

# Database
##########################################################
$dbHost="localhost";
$dbName="drupal_test_db";
$dbUser="test_user";
$dbPassword="xxxxxx";
$dbPort ="3306";
##########################################################

# Admin
##########################################################
$AdminUsername="admin";
$AdminPassword="password";
$adminEmail="admin@example.com";
##########################################################

# Install core
##########################################################
// go to installed dir
drush_op('chdir', $dest);

$status = drush_invoke_process('@self', 'site-install', array('standard'), array(
                                                              'account-mail'=> $adminEmail,
                                                              'account-name' => $AdminUsername,
                                                              'account-pass' => $AdminPassword,
                                                              'site-name' => $siteName,
                                                              'locale' => $siteLocale,
                                                              'db-url' => 'mysql://'.$dbUser.':'.$dbPassword.'@'.$dbHost.':' . $dbPort . '/'.$dbName,
                                                        )
                              );
drush_print('Site Install - ' . (($status) ? 'SUCCESS' : 'FAILURE'));


//check if we can bootstrap
$self = drush_sitealias_get_record('@self');
if (empty($self)) {
    drush_die("I can't bootstrap from the current location.", 0);
}

# Enable modules
##########################################################
//@ToDo read from make file and enable modules
$build_file_parsed = drupal_parse_info_file($build_src);
print_r($build_file_parsed);

# Pre configure settings
##########################################################
//variable_set();
```

I tried different things as described in [drush-isnt-bootstrapping-drush-script](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76877/drush-isnt-bootstrapping-drush-script). I also tried something like creating dynamic alias:

```
$cur_dir = getcwd();
$site = array(
        'root' => $cur_dir,
        'uri' => 'http://default',
        '#name' => 'self',
        'path-aliases' => array(
            '%root' => $cur_dir
        ),
);

drush_bootstrap_max_to_sitealias($site);
```

All of the attempts have failed. How would one bootstrap from currently installed Drupal dir via drush script, so the Drupal API is available? Thank you

EDIT:

So, with a little bit more of understanding of Aliases, Phases and Bootstraping, i have

```
$site2 = drush_sitealias_get_record($cur_dir.'#default');
$boot_status = drush_bootstrap_max_to_sitealias($site2, DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_FULL);
drush_print('Attempting Bootstrap ' . (($boot_status) ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
drush_print('Current bootstap phase: ' . drush_get_context('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_PHASE'));

//perhaps it takes time to bootstrap
while(!drush_has_boostrapped(DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_FULL)){
    sleep(2);
    drush_print('waiting...current phase '.drush_get_context('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_PHASE'));
}
```

This showed that the phase is staying the same '0' even thou the variable 'boot_status' confirming the attempt to bootstrap. Then i looked at the error:

($errors = drush_get_context('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_ERRORS')) ? print_r($errors) : drush_print('no errors') ;

This was printing the following error:

```
[DRUSH_NO_DRUPAL_ROOT] => A Drupal installation directory could not be found
```

I am confused because we are in the new install root directory. In addition, the alias is specifying the root as following(printed $site2):

```
[uri] => default
[root] => /Users/latvian/Sites/drupal/test/test-core
[path-aliases] => Array
    (
        [%root] => /Users/latvian/Sites/drupal/test/test-core
    )

[#name] => .Users.latvian.Sites.drupal.test.test-core#default
```

Why would drush not see the new install root directory? Thank you

Comment: You probably need to change directory into the sites/default folder and execute the install command from there.

Comment: Thank You Chadpeppers, but its already doing here(before 'site-install'), or i am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

i wasn't able to figure out how to bootstrap the new Drupal instance in the installation directory as i would like, but what worked was creating a separate drush script only for configuring the instance and call it from the installation script as following:

```
drush_shell_exec('drush ../config/drush-scripts/configure-site.php --debug --build-src=the-make-file-installing-the-site.make');
```

And the configuration script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush
<?php    

// check if we can bootstrap
$self = drush_sitealias_get_record('@self');
if (empty($self)) {
    drush_die("I can't bootstrap from the current location.", 0);
}

//go to the install dir
drush_op('chdir', $self['root']);


# Enable modules
##########################################################
$build_file_parsed = drupal_parse_info_file($make_file);
$modules_to_enable = array_diff($build_file_parsed['projects'],array('drupal'));
$modules_enabled = drush_invoke_process("@self", "pm-enable", $modules_to_enable);
drush_print('Modules ' . (($modules_enabled) ? 'WAS' : 'WAS NOT' ). '  Enabled');

# Pre configure settings
##########################################################
# disable user pictures
variable_set('user_pictures',0);

# allow only admins to register users
variable_set('user_register',0);

# set site slogan
variable_set('site_slogan',$siteSlogan);

# Configure JQuery update
variable_set('jquery_update_compression_type', "min");
variable_set('jquery_update_jquery_cdn',"google");
variable_set('jquery_update_jquery_version',"1.7");
```

I hope one day it will become apparent why i wasn't able to do all - download, install and configure in one drush script or if you know, please, share